# Transmitting a signal without an external transmitter

Tags: pi-4, uart, signal, repository

I found a repository called [rpitx](https://github.com/F5OEO/rpitx) which can be used to transmit a signal (e.g. the signal of the keyfob of my gate). I'm wondering how this is possible without an external transmitter connected to the raspberry pi?
Maybe the software uses the UART?

Comment: Why don't you just read the README in the repository you link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works by generating signal on the GPIO4. You need to connect piece of wire to the pin and it works only in close proximity of few inches. It is for educational, testing purpose rather than for real applications.